# ObjectListView throws InvalidCastException on SetObjects()

Tags: c#, .net, objectlistview

This Exception was reported through an anonymous error tracking system, so I do not have any additional information about it.

```
System.InvalidCastException 
An object of type 'ListViewSubItem' cannot be converted to type 'BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVListSubItem'.
BrightIdeasSoftware.OLVListItem in get_HasAnyHyperlinks within ObjectListView, Version=2.9.1.1072, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1c5bf581481bcd4
BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView in PostProcessOneRow within ObjectListView, Version=2.9.1.1072, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1c5bf581481bcd4
BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView in PostProcessRows within ObjectListView, Version=2.9.1.1072, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1c5bf581481bcd4
BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView in BuildList within ObjectListView, Version=2.9.1.1072, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1c5bf581481bcd4
BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView in SetObjects within ObjectListView, Version=2.9.1.1072, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b1c5bf581481bcd4
```

Any idea what could cause this?

EDIT: As far as I can tell, the question that was marked as duplicate does not help. Maybe it is worth mentioning, that we only saw this Exception once, while there are several hundred users. So this seems to be some edge case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ObjectListView cast exception (for hit testing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621545/objectlistview-cast-exception-for-hit-testing)

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to be in `HasAnyHyperlinks` in OLVListItem.cs:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets whether any cell on this item is showing a hyperlink
        /// </summary>
        public bool HasAnyHyperlinks {
            get {
                foreach (OLVListSubItem subItem in this.SubItems) {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(subItem.Url))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Only invocation in the codebase seems to be in `PostProcessOneRow` in ObjectListView.cs (this matches your stack trace).

The caller line is:

```
            if (this.UseHyperlinks && olvi.HasAnyHyperlinks) {
                PropagateFormatFromRowToCells(olvi);
                this.ApplyHyperlinkStyle(olvi);
```

So you could probably avoid this issue by setting `UseHyperlinks` to false (if you don't have any).

Alternatively you could put a try/catch around where you are calling SetObjects and try again (assuming your stack trace had some proprietary frames that you dropped out).

Finally `ObjectListView.PostProcessOneRow` is virtual so you could solve it by subclassing ObjectListView and write custom implementation (talk about over engineering though).

In terms of replicating / understanding the problem

`OLVListItem` inherits from `ListViewItem` and `SubItems` is on the base class and public.  So if someone was somehow manually adding regular windows `ListViewSubItems` instead of the olv one (`OLVListSubItem`) that would account for it.  Maybe look to check that none of your code references that property.

If not then presumably some windows magic could mess about with this property? What windows version are they running, any wierd software on the machine? Does it happen for that user all the time or only once?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I see only one single occurrence of this Exception on the logging server. So either the user stopped using the application after it crashed, or it happened only once. But you have a point mentioning the windows version. The logs says `6.1.7601`, which corresponds to `Windows Server 2008 R2, Service Pack 1`! So we may have something here. That is actually the only user so far, that uses that exact OS version.

Comment: No problem.  Only other thought I had was an accessability setting/tool or virus that is changing what's in the tree through the windows API.  Seems bit unlikely though.